# How to print the values of a array which is in another array insted of "[object]"

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

So I have an array of "sessions":

```
var sessions = [];

function Session(title, speaker) {
    this.title = title;
    this.speaker = speaker;
    this.id = nextId;
    this.ratings = [];
    this.currentRatingId = 0;
    this.currentSessionState = SessionState.Created; //SessionState is an enum
}
```

And the session has an array of ratings:

```
function Rating(evaluator,ratingValue) {
    this.ratingId;
    this.ratingValue = ratingValue;
    this.evaluator = evaluator;
    this.evaluatedSession;
}
```

If I print my "sessions" array I get this for example:

```
[Session {
title: 'Javasession',
speaker: 'JavaSpeaker ',
id: 1,
ratings: [[Object], [Object]],
currentRatingId: 2,
currentSessionState: 2
},
Session {
    title: 'C#Session',
    speaker: 'C#Speaker',
    id: 2,
    ratings: [[Object]],
    currentRatingId: 1,
    currentSessionState: 2
}]
```

As you can see the array which is in the array "session" doesn't print the objects. It prints only "[object]"..

Is it somehow possible to print the values of each array which is in another arrays without using any loops (for,foreach).... ?

Comment: you could try `console.log(JSON.stringify(sessions));`

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer hanks it works. But the "problem" is that it doesn't print very "nice". it just prints everything in one line which makes it quite unreadable

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(sessions, null, '  '))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [console.dir()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) in browser.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    subArr: [
        {
          subSubArr:[
            {
              a:1
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
  }
];
console.dir(arr, { depth: null });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON#stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method to print it as a `string`.

***Example:***

```js
const arr = [
  {
    subArr: [
        {
          subSubArr:[
            {
              a:1
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
  }
];
const res = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: and if you want it printed with formatting you can use `JSON.stringify(arr,null,2);`

Comment: @MohamedAbbas thanks it works. But the "problem" is that it doesn't print very "nice". it just prints everything in one line which makes it quite unreadable

Comment: @KeyNavas you're welcome, You may need to pass `null, 2` values as @Andrew Lohr mentioned. So your code will be `const res = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.dir` with `{ depth: null }`

using a simplified array:

```
let sessions =  [ Session: { ratings: [ {Rating: 1}, {Rating: 2} ] } ];
```

Running `console.log(sessions);` results in:

```
[ { Session: { ratings: [Object] } } ]
```

Running `console.dir(sessions, { depth: null})` results in:

```
[ { Session: { ratings: [ { Rating: 1 }, { Rating: 2 } ] } } ]
```